# C++ Using 'this' as non-type template parameter not allowed

Tags: c++

I have two classes, `BlockType` and `BlockInstance`. `BlockInstance` takes a `BlockType &` as a template parameter. I am not completely fluent in C++ and would like to know why I can't pass this as the template parameter inside `BlockType` when defining a function that returns a  `BlockInstance` type.

Code:

```
class BlockType;

template <BlockType & blockType>
class BlockInstance;

class BlockType{
public:
    virtual BlockInstance<this> & createInstance(block_pos pos) = 0;

    virtual void render(BlockInstance<this> & blockInstance) = 0;
};

template <BlockType & blockType>
class BlockInstance{
public:
    block_pos && pos;

    BlockInstance(block_pos & pos);

    virtual void onClientUpdate() = 0;
};
```

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Template parameters do not need to be types, class or otherwise.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ If that was the case `std::integer_sequence` would not work.

Comment: @Boundary Well, may be not the complete correct wording.

Comment: I think you might be better off not using a template and instead pass `this` to `BlockInstance` through a constructor.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: No, it certainly isn't.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Or `std::array`. Or the introductory "Hello World"-like example on calculating factorials using templates.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: [Not just literals](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b6d7a50d5c7f47fc). Perhaps you shouldn't comment on questions about topics with which you are not familiar!

Comment: @BoundaryImposition what a waste of learning opportunities that would be.

Comment: @Quentin: Granted!

Comment: @Boundary Sir. what I know for sure is that `this` doesn't fall into any catregories that it can be used as a  _template parameter_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Well, of course you do: I said so in my answer 2 hours ago ;)

Comment: @Boundary That's why I'm calling you _'sir'_ all the time (not the usual "culture clash").

Answer (score 2):

This is an improper use of templates, which are for (effectively) code generation based on quantities known at the time you compile your program.

`this` is a pointer with a value known only at runtime.

It's hard to make a concrete recommendation here, as you did not explain what it is that you are trying to do. But it seems likely that you just want to pass the pointer as a normal function argument.